# Drill down option in Snowsight in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using Snowflake for datawarehouse purpose. I am currently exploring Snowsight app under Snowflake for data visualization. Is there drill down option when we are visualizing the data in Snowsight?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not a feature that is listed in the documentation:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-visualizations.html

They are constantly releasing new features though so I can imagine this would be something coming in the future.

Comment: Thank you Dan, can we plug other BI tools like Power BI with snowflake for using visualization capabilities?

Comment: yes you can connect BI tools to Snowflake, like MicroStrategy, Tableau, Looker, Sigma, Power BI, Qlik etc..